# Bugs in VertexContract function?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I think there may be two bugs in the VertexContract function:

1) The updated graph does not include reasonable edgeweights
2) The function does not actually reduce the number of vertices in the graph. If I have n vertices, and I merge m of them, I would expect to have n-m+1 vertex after the operation.

Let me run through a simple example. In the following a simple graph is built:

```
gr = { {"a" \[DirectedEdge] "b", 1000}, {"b" \[DirectedEdge] "c", 2000}, {"c" \[DirectedEdge] "d", 3000}, {"d" \[DirectedEdge] "a", 4000}}

test1 = Graph[  (First[#]) & /@ gr, VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeWeight -> (Last[#] & /@ gr), EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

The graph, then, is:

[image: Graph With weights]

I now wish to merge vertices a and b:

```
test2 = VertexContract[test1, {"a", "b"}]
```

which gives me the following graph:

[image]

Now, as you can see, the edge weights are now strangely set to all 1's, even on the c -> d edge that is not modified.

```
Normal[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[test2]  ]
```

Yields

```
{{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Clearly showing that:

- There is one vertex too many: There should be three, but there are 4 (including a phantom one with all 0's in the weights)
- The weights are all reduced to 1 for some reason.

If I do

```
VertexList[test2]
```

I get

```
{"c", "d", "a", 1}
```

There is a phantom node lying around, as you can see in the graph above and in the vertex list. I had expected {c, d, 1}.

Are these bugs? Is the new vertex always added as the last one in the vertex list?  Are there workarounds?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 6):

1) is not a bug. It's a missing feature. There should be a way to decide how to combine the weights of edges (and vertices) when contracting vertices.

2) looks like a bug (from your description), but it doesn't seem to be present in M11.2 anymore.

Here's how to handle (1) using [the IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

Consider this test graph:

```
style = {VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"};
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3}, 
  EdgeWeight -> {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, style]
```

[image]

Let's contract vertices 1 and 2 using the `IGVertexContract` function. If we turn off self-loop and multi-edge removal, the edge ordering will be strictly preserved. This allows us to manually re-add edge weights, but we will end up with a multigaph.

```
gc = IGVertexContract[g, {{1, 2}}, SelfLoops -> True, MultiEdges -> True, 
         EdgeWeight -> IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight][g]]
```

[image]

Now we merge parallel edges and add up their weights:

```
IGWeightedSimpleGraph[gc, style, SelfLoops -> False]
```

[image]

`IGWeightedSimpleGraph` can also combine weights using other combiner functions (e.g. multiply them instead of adding them up). See its second argument.